# Data cleaning on dictionary of .CSV files

Tags: python, database, csv, glob, data-cleaning

I'm trying to figure out a nice implementation to drop selected columns from a set of CSV files. I've got a directory of CSV files that I want to aggregate time-series data from but only want the values and the timestamp. I would like to drop just the other columns and I'm also curious about how to do this sort of task after globbing files together. So far what I have is some thing like:

```
files = glob.glob("../dir/subdir/*.csv")
data = {os.path.basename(fname):pd.read_csv(fname) for fname in files}
for df in data:
     df.drop(columns = ['A', 'D'])
```

This doesn't work for a few reasons, but how can I achieve my goal?

Comment: Use `inplace=True`

Comment: use inplace=True or df = df.drop(columns = ['A', 'D']), after that, you should also write data back to csv files, using to_csv()

Comment: Your not iterating over the values in the dictionary.

Comment: What are you really trying to do? Do you need data elsewhere? Do you just want to drop the columns? Is there a reason you mention wanting to aggregate all the dataframes?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you wanted to keep columns 'B' and 'C'. And you are just wanting to clean the data as per your last sentence, meaning you just want the job done so Python isn't specifically required, then this command-line one-liner will create a new .csv for you with just the second and third columns:

```
awk 'FNR == 1 {next} BEGIN {FS=","} {print $2","$3}' *.csv > new.csv
```

I assume you would want a fully concatenated file in the end to read into a DataFrame, so it is set to read each .csv file starting from the second line, so you'll have to replace the header after it's made.

My apologies if this must be done using DataFrames, I'm rather new here.